# error: Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to use this code to extract some values:

main

```
// refhls : array 
foreach($refhls as $refhl){
    $abc = $this->getArrayIntervenants($refhl);
}
```

function

```
public function getArrayIntervenants($refhl){
    $requete = $this->bdd->bd->prepare('SELECT intervenant FROM detailsfiche WHERE ref_hl = :ref_hl');
    $requete->bindValue(':ref_hl', $refhl, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $requete->execute(); // -----MARKED LINE-----
    return $requete->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Doing that I get this error message on the marked line:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in file.php on line 138

How do I fix that please ?

Comment: do you want to insert all the values in array? or any single value>

Comment: What is the value of $refhl? If it is an array then you have an unequal set of keys to values I believe.

Comment: @aowie1, it's a string

Comment: @FerozAkbar, I want to insert all of the output values of the request into an array.

Answer (score 0):

$refhl is an array. You cannot use array as string.

Try to check the string inside array by

```
isset($refh1[$positionKey]) { }
```

if the value exist, and then use it!

Comment: it's not an array, it's just a variable. Does php takes arguments as variables ?

Comment: yes fela, it does. sorry by late but you can use a argument as as variable, also can use a variable as a class method too, php 5.3 plus is greating things up.

Answer (score 0):

Since your variable $refhl is an array, you cannot directly bind it in. Calling a var_dump in the beginning of your function will help you.

> var_dump($refhl);

You can then replace your line with something like this:

```
$requete->bindValue(':ref_hl', $refhl['myArrayKey'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: it's not an array, it's just a variable. Does php takes arguments as variables ?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not an array? Did you try `var_dump($refhl)` in your function? If it's an array that has only one element, you can try `$requete->bindValue(':ref_hl', current($refhl), PDO::PARAM_INT);`